# Get parameter contexts from Nifi custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to create a Nifi (v1.17.0) custom processor with a property having several possible values. These values are generated during the execution of the previous processors in the flow.

The flow is as follows:

Processor A : Generate a yaml file.
Processor B : (the one I've been trying to create) Get the values in the yaml file generated previously and use them to populate a property in order to let the user select the one he needs. The process will then be adapted depending on the value selected.
I've found a solution based on the property method `identifiesControllerService(DistributedMapCacheClient.class)`. It offers the possibility to have a property based on a dropdown menu with several possible choice (use a controller service or parameter contexts).
My idea is to use a parameter contexts available for the processor. So I would like to add the values I need in a Parameter context. This has to be done in the Processor A (which is also a custom processor) in order to use them in the property in the Processor B.

But I didn't find any way to add a parameter in the Parameter context programmaticaly in the `onTrigger` method of the Processor A. How can I add this parameter?

Comment: `add a parameter in the Parameter context programmaticaly in the onTrigger method` - sounds not right. `onTrigger` - called when your processor is running and this means that you can't customize parameters while it's running... something wrong with your idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
Do you think of something I could do to resolve my problem except adding a parameter ? 
I need to populate a property dynamically in my custom processor

Comment: dynamically based on what?

Comment: based on a file generated by a previous custom processor

Comment: but every next file could be different - do you want this dynamic parameter to be different?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't precise enough...
The file is generated when I add the custom processor into the canvas.
So the file will be the same.

I just need to populate the parameter based on a file which doesn't exist when I build the custom processor.